Cosimplicial resolution associated to a monad
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $\mathbf{T}$ a monad on $\mathcal{C}$ with functor part $T : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ (I would actually like to consider the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is an $(\infty, 1)$-category). Let $\operatorname{Am} : \mathcal{C} \to \operatorname{Fun}(\Delta_+, \mathcal{C})$ be the functorial cosimplicial resolution induced by $\mathbf{T}$. What's the relationship between $\operatorname{Am}(T(X))$ and $T \circ \operatorname{Am}(X)$? I know that the latter is split because it equals $U^{\mathbf{T}}\circ F^{\mathbf{T}} \circ \operatorname{Am}(X)$ where $F^{\mathbf{T}} \dashv U^{\mathbf{T}}$ is the monadic adjunction induced by $\mathbf{T}$, and the resolution induced by a monad associated to an adjunction is always split after pushing it through the left adjoint. I would like it if $\operatorname{Am}(T(X))$ were a limit diagram, and this is true in a couple of cases I checked, but I'm not sure how to prove it in general. Probably I'm missing some basic connection between the two cosimplicial objects? It's not hard to see the difference between them on the level of coface/codegenaracy maps, one has an extra "outside" layer of $T$ on the unit/multiplication while the other has an extra "inside" layer.

Let $\Delta_{\infty}, \Delta_{-\infty} \subseteq \Delta$ be the wide subcategories of the simplex category containing the maps which preserve maxima and which preserve minima, respectively. Define $i : \Delta_+ \to \Delta_{-\infty}$ by $i(x) = [0] \oplus x$ and $j : \Delta_+ \to \Delta_{\infty}$ by $j(x) = x \oplus [0]$. Let $k : \Delta_{-\infty} \to \Delta_+$ and $\ell : \Delta_{\infty} \to \Delta_+$ be the inclusions. I didn't find a direct relationship between $T \circ \operatorname{Am}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Am}(T(X))$ but I did notice that $T \circ \operatorname{Am}(X) = \operatorname{Am}(X) \circ k \circ i$ while $\operatorname{Am}(T(X)) = \operatorname{Am}(X) \circ \ell \circ j$; this is essentially just the description of the coface and codegenaracy maps I sketched in the OP. And I think this is sufficient to show $\operatorname{Am}(T(X))$ is a limit diagram.
The nlab claims that $i$ is an absolute limit cone, hence $k \circ i$ is an absolute limit cone. But $k\circ i$ and $\ell \circ j$ are isomorphic in $\operatorname{Arr}(\mathsf{Cat})$, specifically they are conjugate via the nontrivial automorphism of $\Delta_+$ (reverse the order on every object), and so $\ell \circ j$ is also an absolute limit cone. But then $\operatorname{Am}(T(X)) = \operatorname{Am}(X) \circ \ell \circ j$ is a limit cone, as desired.
Edit: I think if I knew more about décalage I would frame this in those terms? Something like, if we have a comonad $W$ on $\mathcal{C}$ then the décalage of $\operatorname{Am}_W(X)$ is $\operatorname{Am}_W(W(X))$? But I'm not confident this is correct, or that it would give a quicker proof that $\operatorname{Am}_W(W(X))$ is a colimit diagram
